# Does it make any sense to delete copy/assignment operators on a purely static public interface in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a class that has one public static method and a few private methods in C++. Does it make any sense to explicitly delete (see code below) the copy and assignment operators in this case?

```
public:
    static MyReturnType* CreateSomeMock(const myType input);

    MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;

private:
    static ...
```

I'm inclined to say that I shouldn't worry about someone trying to copy or assign to a default constructed class with no instance variables. I'm just not 100% and am curious what the community thinks is a best practice.

**UPDATE 1**

I've moved the private methods to just be non-member functions defined in the .cpp file. The header still contains the public member function `CreateSomeMock` and I'm still curious about the assignment/copy-construction =).

**UPDATE 2**

This "class" is essentially a namespace. I appreciate all the answers around this point and also want to keep this on topic of the `= delete` part of the question in this case (which I agree at this point should really be avoided...but I'm case-in-point that it happens sometimes).

Comment: I'd ask if it makes sense for it to be a class at all.

Comment: No arguments there, it's really more of a function. Specifically, it's a factory class.

Comment: I can't see the reason for this being a class, but if you really want one, you could just disable the constructor. If you can't construct it, you won't be able to copy it.

Comment: Is the private static part a member variable, or just the methods you moved? Do you have static data anywhere in this class?

Comment: Because you have deleted the copy constructor and copy assignment operator, users can't create a default-constructed instance of `MyClass` so it's not an issue. That said, I agree with @juanchopanza in that this isn't much of a class at all. What you really want is a module...

Comment: I'd say make it a non-member function and then you don't even have to worry about copy/assignment etc.

Comment: @Dutow It was just methods. No variables. Really this was made a class simply to organize it in our code. It's essentially a namespace. I've spoken with a few co-workers about this and we came to the conclusion that this class really exists for organizational purposes and isn't really (even though we're treating it like it is) a class.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes it does. You can later on specialize a template on a static class; to my knowledge, you cannot do that on a namespace.

Comment: @lorro Who said this was a class template?

Comment: Following others' suggestions about not being constructible will match up with [C# static classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Comment: @juanchopanza: not this.. Any other. A template class that takes *this* class as the template parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between a class with one (or more) static functions, and a few functions within namespaces is when you use templates: you can use the class as a template parameter, but not a namespace.

Alternatively, you could use the static method as the template parameter, but that won't scale when you add more method to your class or namespace.

E.g. if you have:

```
class X {
public:
  static void a();
  static void b();
};
```

You can use it in a template as `some_template<X>`, and your templates could call a and b on the template parameter:

```
template<typename T>
void some_template() { T::a(); T::b(); }
```

But if `X` is a namespace, you would need two template parameters
: `some_template<X::a, X::b>`

If this is a valid use case, so you really do need a static class, you probably want to avoid accidentally creating an instance of it.

A practical reason for that is that in C++, every object requires a size bigger than zero: when somebody accidentally creates an instance of this class, it will have a cost, even if minimal.

Comment: there isn't a good analogy for a `protected` `static` member function in a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It cant hurt to `delete` them, this way a default one wont be created for you by the compiler. You should however [follow the rule of 3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and explicitly declare the destructor (not that it matters).

This class is then pretty pointless though. It seems like you should instead declare non-member functions as part of a namespace:

```
namespace myFactoryPattern {
    MyReturnType* CreateSomeMock(const myType input);
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is called static class. It differs from a namespace (which you might consider as an alternative) in that a template can be specialized over it. It's expected, but not required that you delete: (either in the class, or a base class)

- Default, copy and move constructors
- Copy and move assignment

Or, alternatively you might delete:

- Destructor (disallowing non-pointers and `delete`)
- `operator new(size_t)` and `operator new[](size_t)` (disallowing `new` to a naked pointer that's never deleted)

The latter has the fun factor of surprising everyone and stealing hours from their time to understand what's going on and why they cannot create and instance.

Or - you might just allow instances. It really hurts no-one, experienced programmers won't create any; but you might still pass it to template functions that expect a member to be passed given your static methods fulfil the interface required.